# Laravel 5.3 Deployment Tool

Tags: laravel, deployment, packaging

Just finished developing a web application using laravel 5.3,  how can i create an installation procedures (html,script) like that of wordpress that will create database,run a script to create tables,  create .env file and sort of stuff/

Is there any package that can do this?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't know about the downvote but i'm looking for something like this.  https://github.com/RachidLaasri/LaravelInstaller   but i got an error on this when using it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use homestead or vagrant you could write a script to configure your bootstrap.sh and vagrantfile to provision your box and install your box. Then have it vagrant up to start your box.

bootstrap.sh file can be found https://www.vagrantup.com/intro/getting-started/provisioning.html. Homestead has a folder scripts that shows all the different scripts and the configuration that can be used to provision your box. You would simply just write a script to automate the installation of homestead or vagrant and that should be it.

Comment: can i achieve it as like this https://github.com/RachidLaasri/LaravelInstaller ?  please see screenshot at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

If you are pushing this out into the wild and need to automate builds, run unit tests and create migrations you could use https://jenkins.io/